# SharePoint 2013 Active Directory Profile Picture URL Incorrect

Tags: active-directory, user-profile-service, profile-sync

When user images sync from active directory the image url is https://example.com/sites/mysitesUser%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/user_MThumb.jpg.  I'm missing a slash after mysites.  If I manually upload an image within CA it works perfectly.  Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: check this http://blogs.technet.com/b/harmeetw/archive/2012/09/18/sharepoint-2010-profile-pictures-not-showing-up-due-to-incorrect-url.aspx

Comment: or another way to try to run the Update-SPProfilePhotoStore  NewBaseURI switch with a trailing slash.How you enter the Mysite Host URl in the UPA is it http://mysite or Http://mysite/?

Comment: I add it like http://mysite

Comment: try to add the trailing slash at the end "/" , test it , if it works fine otherwise run full sync.

Comment: Adding the trailing slash didn't work.

Comment: what about running the update command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their are couple of ways to fix this kind of issue.

- Update the Mysite Host with trailing Slash i.e http://mysite/
- We can update this manually by going to user profile properties inside user profile service application and linking it to the correct picture.
- Use the powershell to update this.

  here is code:

  ```
      $site = get-spsite "http://SiteCollection"     $context=  [Microsoft.office.server.servercontext]::GetContext($site) 
  $userProfileManager = new-object Microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager($context) 
  $profiles = $userProfileManager.GetEnumerator() 
     foreach ($profile in $profiles) 
      { 
      $Matchurl = "http://mysitehost/User PhotosProfile Pictures" 
      #Provide the incorrect URL for the picture 
       if($profile["pictureurl"].value -match $matchurl) 
          { 

              Write-host $profile["AccountName"].value "contains incorrect url" 
              $CurrentURL = $profile["Pictureurl"].value 
              $CurrentURL = $CurrentURL.tostring() 
              $GoodUrl = "http://mysitehost/User Photos/Profile Pictures" 
              #Provide the correct URL for the picture 
              $CorrectUrl = $CurrentURL.replace($matchurl,$goodurl) 
              $profile["pictureurl"].value = $correcturl 
              $profile.commit() 
              Write-host $profile["AccountName"].value "PictureURL has been corrected" 
     } 
  }
  ```

http://blogs.technet.com/b/harmeetw/archive/2012/09/18/sharepoint-2010-profile-pictures-not-showing-up-due-to-incorrect-url.aspx

Comment: This worked.  Though, now I'll have to run a job every night after the profiles sync to correct the picture urls.  Seems a little strange that I'd have to do that every night.