# Creating MySite - Configure over 443 or Extend?

Tags: 2013, my-site

I have decided to recreate MySite Web App with all the issues I am having.  My question is:

Should I create it under some port like 1234 and use http://mysite/localhost/?  Then extend it to my domain name I have in the DNS under port 443?  Or simply configure it under 443 and the domain name?

Thanks,
Robb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Most installations work fine with a separate WebApplication for MySites. I recommend to use same ApplicationPool-Account, as you do not have that much permission-trouble. Security-Freaks may disagree with this.
- If possible, use your existing URL (like you already mentioned above: http://mysite). Avoid using non-standard-Ports (stay at 80 or 443). You save yourself lots of [SingleSignOn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2012/06/05/the-intranet-zone/) and [Kerberos-Issues](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502606(v=office.14).aspx)
- Deleting and recreating MySites is not all you have to do. You have some Properties in UserProfileService ([PersonalSiteCapabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.userprofiles.personalsitecapabilities.aspx), [PersonalSiteInstantiationState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.userprofiles.personalsiteinstantiationstate.aspx), [PictureURL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139593/sharepoint-2013-active-directory-profile-picture-url-incorrect)) which must be reset to their defaults. Sometimes it is easier to recreate MySites and UserProfileService. That heavily depends on how much UPSA was customized.

Comment: Both very helpful answers - thanks! I marked MHeld because there was a little more info.  Sorry Trevor for not being clear, re-reading it was a bit confusing.  Basically I configured SP2013 before I had a FQDN and with all the issues I was having I wanted to recreate MySites.  I ended up re-creating the farm using the FQDNs and standard ports and things are working like they should.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite understanding what you're attempting to accomplish, but extending or using zones other than Default is discouraged. I would recommend you simply publish over https://mysite.company.com.